Issue with with implementing express-session authentication with React Context and useReducer
I'm currently working on implementing authentication using express-session on the backend and React Context with useReducer on the frontend. The authentication itself is functioning properly, as I'm able to authenticate users and maintain their authenticated state across page navigation because I'm facing an issue when the page is refreshed.
The problem is that upon page refresh, the user data stored in the React Context is lost, resulting in user being undefined. I understand that this is because the useEffect hook in my AuthProvider component is only triggered on mount, and I need a way to persist the user data across page refreshes.
I've attempted to fetch the user data from the server upon component mount using useEffect, but this approach doesn't seem to solve the issue of data persistence upon page refresh.
Can someone please provide guidance on how to update my code to ensure that the user data persists across page refreshes?
Thank you in advance
AuthContext
import {
  createContext,
  useReducer,
  useContext,
  ReactNode,
  Dispatch,
  useEffect
} from 'react';
import { RequestService } from '../services';

const LOGIN = 'LOGIN';
const LOGOUT = 'LOGOUT';

interface IUser {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  birthDate: Date;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  image: string;
}

type AuthState = {
  isAuthenticated: boolean;
  user: IUser | null;
};

type AuthProviderProps = {
  children: ReactNode;
};

type AuthAction =
  | { type: 'LOGIN'; payload: { user: IUser } }
  | { type: 'LOGOUT' };

const authReducer = (state: AuthState, action: AuthAction) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOGIN:
      return {
        ...state,
        isAuthenticated: true,
        user: action.payload.user
      };
    case LOGOUT:
      return {
        ...state,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        user: null
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const AuthContext = createContext<{
  isAuthenticated: boolean;
  user: IUser | null;
  dispatch: Dispatch<AuthAction>;
}>({
  isAuthenticated: false,
  user: null,
  dispatch: () => {}
});

export const AuthProvider: React.FC<AuthProviderProps> = ({ children }) => {
  const cookie = document.cookie.includes('sessionId');
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(authReducer, {
    isAuthenticated: cookie,
    user: null
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkSession = async () => {
      try {
        const { authenticated, user } = await RequestService.get(
          '/auth/session'
        );
        if (authenticated && user) {
          dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN', payload: user });
        } else {
          dispatch({ type: 'LOGOUT' });
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    };

    checkSession();
  }, []);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ ...state, dispatch }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext);

auth.controller.ts
// Check if user is user session is active and is not expired
export const checkSession = asyncHandler(
  async (req: Request<IUser>, res: Response) => {
    if (req.session.userId && Number(req.session.cookie.originalMaxAge) > 0) {
      const userId = stringToObjectId(req.session.userId);

      const user = await UserService.getUserInfo(userId);

      res.status(200).json({ authenticated: true, user });
    } else {
      throw new AuthenticationError(messages.auth.unauthorized);
    }
  }
);

Header component
export default function Header() {
  const { isAuthenticated, user, dispatch } = useAuth();

  console.log('user', user); // Undefined after refresh
}

